# Add checkbox to single product & hook into woocommerce

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to customize 1 of my woocommerce products. I can add checkboxes to the product with images, etc without a problem, however I don't know how to hook into woocommerce in order to have woocommerce save the input, pass it to the cart, checkout, and finally to the order. Currently the inputs for the order are lost as soon as the product is added to the cart.
Can anybody point me into the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Try [Product Add-ons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons)

Comment: hi, doesnt work unfortunately because my checkboxes need to be images. Add-ons doesnt have this functionality - already contacted them concerning this. thanks for the heads up though, any other ideas? :)

Comment: I would still probably start with add-ons and customize from there. A quick javascript to turn checkboxes/radios into images is probably easier than figuring out the cart aspect of WooCommerce.

Comment: ok, thanks. can you potentially recommend a good plugin other than the woocommerce gravity forms product add-on?

Comment: Don't know if it will do what you want, but there is a Ninja Forms product add-on alternative.

Comment: thanks, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility to add some HTML and/or CSS to your product page. try this. You should use a form plugin so that they values are actually saved in the database. Try: http://www.gravityforms.com/

When you input your form into the page, the HTML will probably look something like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/><label for="thing"></label>
```

Since that is a checkbox we can add some CSS to this, and with CSS we can add a background image like this:

```css
    input[type=checkbox] {
      background: url('http://domain.com/img/off.png') no-repeat;
      height: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked {
      background: url('http://domain.com/img/on.png') no-repeat;
      height: 25px;
      width: 25px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    }
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing" />
<label for="thing">Checkbox</label>
```

I have changed the size of chekcbox when check so you can see it works. Just paste in your pictures URL.

Comment: Hey Robin, thanks for your answer. I'm currently using gravity forms and using the description field of the checkboxes for adding the images (they're html enabled). Does someone know how gravity forms adds the values to the database to have them saved? Then I could leave out the gravity form and make my page leaner ;)   Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi. I dont know Gravity forms, but i would assume it uses standard functions in wordpress to save to database. If you have access to your database i would first check if there is a table called something with gravity or under table XXX_options (wp_options or h43_options) to find  a row with some information like that. But this is the hard way, maybe someone else have suggestions.